# Alternative to deprecated ExcelUtil.calculateColWidth() from Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

Please could someone tell me what I should use instead, to get the column width in 1/256th of a character width.I need it to set column width but I don't want to use deprecated ExcelUtil class. Thank you in advance!

```
sheet.setColumnWidth(1, ExcelUtil.calculateColWidth(10.71));
```

Comment: I want to update from 3.10 to 3.17. I checked but I didn't see any alternative method.

Comment: Did you try the `AbstractExcelUtils.getColumnWidthInPx()`?

Comment: I used it, thank you!